# Group does not show up in groups command

Tags: users, group

I added a new group. Then I logged out, and logged back in, but the groups command does not show the group. If I try to add the group, I get an error. What gives?

```
me@z80hd2:~$ groupadd sdk_users
groupadd: group 'sdk_users' already exists
me@z80hd2:~$ groups
me adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
me@z80hd2:~$
```

Comment: The `groups` command prints *the groups a user is in* - it does not list all the groups that may exist

Comment: Use `usermod -a -G sdk_users me` to add yourself to the new group.  Then relog.

Comment: try `grep sdk_users /etc/group` to see if sdk_users is in local group (local=group defined in the host you are in).

Answer (score 1):

Because you are me as a user :).
So you can only see the groups you are in.
If you want to see the group you created, you should look at /etc/group:

```
cat /etc/group | grep sdk_users
sdk_users:x:1001:
```

Check [here](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/etcgroup-file-explained/) for more.

Answer (score 0):

The `groupadd` command creates a group on the system. It does not make your user a member of that group.

The `groups` command will list group memberships for your user account, and won't tell you about system groups that you don't belong to.

Unless you have a complex authentication system, the group has most likely been added to the /etc/group file, which is why `groupadd sdk_users` tells you the group exists. You can check that it exists by running `grep sdk_users /etc/group`.

A typical entry in /etc/group contains a list of of the form

```bash
GROUP_NAME:PASSWORD:NUMERIC_GID:USER1,USER2,USER3
```

The password is typically 'x' meaning no password.
If the users part is blank, then no users are a member of the group.

Based on the fact that you're expecting results from logging out and running `group`, I assume you are expecting your user to be a member of sdk_users. `groupadd` does not add your user. You'll need to run another command to add your user to the group. On Debian-based systems (and I assume others) the command is

```bash
usermod --append --groups sdk_users me
```

This modifies group membership for the user "me" to include the group "sdk_users", in addition to all the groups you're already a member of.

Once your user is added to the group, you'll need to log out and back in. Then you should see the new group listed when you run `groups`.

To learn more about usermod, you can type `man usermod` at the terminal, or just do an internet search for "usermod manpage", however after looking over the groupadd manpage I can definitely see that the information isn't necessarily clear enough for someone new to *nix.